# Plot triangulated geometry with vector field and magnitude contour

Tags: python, matlab, plot, gnuplot

I have triangulated geometry (STL file) and I have the values of a vector field for each triangle. I want to plot the triangles with the vector field on each triangle and also color the triangle according to the magnitude of the vector.
Is there any way of accomplishing this using languages like python or any open-source software such as gnuplot,etc.?
If not, what about software like MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29 you can store color and normal informations in a STL binary file. I'd make a python script that creates a new binary STL where each facet (triangle) has a color and use the normal to store the vector. Then I'd import this file in Blender and ask it to display the normals and the flat face colors. You'll then do an OpenGL render (it is just a button to push) to export a PNG file of the view you want to see.
Do you have a sample scene ?

Comment: No I don't. I have not used Blender before. I will give it a try and reply.

Comment: I mean, do you have a sample STL and the values of the vector field for each triangle ?

Comment: I have a sample stl file and values of vector fields. Here's the link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zsuwf0f86wyyrtv/dqS-siCSyn. The .dat file has following columns: Triangle no. in stl File, X,Y and Z co-ordinates of triangle centroids, X, Y and Z components of vector field. I tried opening this stl file in Blender, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: What was unsuccessful ? Import the STL ? Import you .dat ? Both ?

Comment: Blender is unable to recognise the original stl file itself.

Comment: You my have to activate the STL import / export addon.

Comment: OK. Its opening now. But the ASCII format of stl file supports only one color. Even if I create a binary version, I still don't understand  how I can plot the vector field (as arrows) on individual surfaces?

Comment: There is an option in Blender to display the normal of each face. If you encode your vector as a face normal, you should be able to display them in blender. I am sorry I can not check on your files, my internet connection is so bad right now I cannot even access your dropbox archive.